# Contribution Ant Design Core Codebase,

Tags: antd

I used ant design in my projects. I like to contribute. 
i clone the repo and run locally. But my question is if I change any code how can I see the output or test or debug any component 
i need some instruction

Comment: You didn't explain on which project you working on, Angular? React? Vue? Every project is independent please refer to my answer and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Look for **Contributing** section on the relevant `antd` project official website.

For example, [contributing section in react](https://ant.design/docs/react/contributing).

Moreover, in every respected `github` repository, check for [`.github` folder](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/tree/master/.github) or `How to contribute` section in the `README.md` file - it has all the information necessary.

Finally, I suggest using the actual platform (`github`) to communicate with the project you want to contribute, for any question try asking in the [**issues** section.](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues)